How many electrons with energy of 1MeV pass through plexiglass that's 2cm wide?
I am an undergraduate student and have a question. I was doing a Compton experiment and was using plexiglass to minimize electrons from radioactive source.
I was wondering how many electrons can pass through it. I took to calculate the number of electrons $N=N_0e^{-\nu x}$, which is analogous to Beer-Lambert's law for photons. But I need to calculate the absorption coefficient first.
I was thinking about using Bethe-Bloch formula to calculate the coefficient, like $\nu=(-dE/dx)/1 \text{ MeV}$, but I am not sure if it's the right approach, because I've been getting weird results. Does anyone have an advice?

The interaction of charged particles with matter is not as straightforward as the interaction of photons with matter. The exponential decay of photons is a reduction of the actual number of photons that are in the material at any given moment. These photons are being absorbed by different physical processes. When electrons interact with matter, they're not being absorbed. They're losing energy, mainly through braking radiation and ionization processes, but they're not absorbed. The number of electrons is not reduced exponentially with depth.
What you would typically talk about is the range of the particles, the mean distance the particles can traverse in the material. For heavy charged particles, one can think of the range as the distance at which no more particles are detected (unlike with photons), and at shorter distances all particles traverse the material (excepto for some straggling). But for lighter particles, such as electrons, this is not really the case and the variation in the number of particles detected at every depth is smoother. Also, lighter particles are scattered within the material and therefore do not penetrate perpendicularly. Their trajectories are erratic, their traversed distance is not equal to the penetration depth.
The simplest approximation is the "continuously slowing down approximation" or CSDA. One assumes that the energy loss is always equal to the stopping power. Therefore the range is
$$R_{\mathrm{CSDA}} = \int_{E_{K,0}}^{0} \frac{\mathrm{d}E_K}{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}E_K}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)}= \int_0^{E_{K,0}} \frac{\mathrm{d}E_K}{S_{\mathrm{tot}}(E_K)}.$$
It can be shown that this range is equal to
$$R_{\mathrm{CSDA}} = \frac{M}{z^2}F(\beta, \mathrm{constants \ of \ the \ material)}, $$
where $M$ is the mass of the particle, $z$ is its charge and $F$ is a function of the velocity of the particle and some constants of the material. The CSDA range can be approximated to the maximum range (range at which no more particles are detected), especially for materials with lower $Z$. If you just want to determine whether any (or almost any) electrons cross through the glass, the simplest way would be to calculate the CSDA range and see if it is larger or smaller than the thickness of the glass.

Not a solution, but you only asked for advice:
If you go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula, it says in the 1st paragraph, that the equation doesn't apply exactly for electrons due to their small mass and indistinguishability, and the may lose energy to bremsstrahlung.
The Bethe-Bloch equation is derived from long-range Coulomb interactions with atomic electrons, while brem is dominated by the high charge density (and hence strong electric field) near the nucleus. They are very different processes.
The source of information for experimental physicists is the Particle Data Group: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/reviews/rpp2022-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf
Regarding apply Beer-Lambert's law for a dE/dx is that it requires that ionization is "smooth". It is not. The energy-loss is described by a Landau distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_distribution), that is, there is a long tail with a small (but greater than exponential suppression) probability of large energy loss interactions. The Landau distribution is notoriously difficult to implement numerically.
The answer you want may be tabulated somewhere. It appears plexiglass (or plastic) $\beta$ shields are an industry standard (https://www.belart.com/bel-art-f24976-0001-acrylic-beta-shield-8-x-12-x-14.html):

It's possible the product description has some information.
Finally, you could just measure it yourself.
